# Unique array from a mysql query

Tags: php

Unfortunately I have one of those moments when my mind just feels frozen.
Therefore I really need some hints on what am I doing wrong:

I'm getting multiple rows based on a category_id with:

```
$certificates= $DB->get_records('prog', array('category'=>$_POST['something']),'', $fields='*');
```

this returns:

```
Array
(
    [1] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 1
            [category] =&gt; 1
            [sortorder] =&gt; 0
            [fullname] =&gt; First Aid Kit Certification
            [shortname] =&gt; CP101
            [idnumber] =&gt; 
            [summary] =&gt; 
            [endnote] =&gt; 
            [visible] =&gt; 1
            [availablefrom] =&gt; 0
            [availableuntil] =&gt; 0
            [available] =&gt; 1
            [timecreated] =&gt; 1561637136
            [timemodified] =&gt; 1561637944
            [usermodified] =&gt; 2
            [icon] =&gt; 
            [exceptionssent] =&gt; 0
            [audiencevisible] =&gt; 2
            [certifid] =&gt; 1
            [assignmentsdeferred] =&gt; 0
            [allowextensionrequests] =&gt; 1
        )

    [2] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 2
            [category] =&gt; 1
            [sortorder] =&gt; 1
            [fullname] =&gt; Program fullname 101
            [shortname] =&gt; P101
            [idnumber] =&gt; 
            [summary] =&gt; 
            [endnote] =&gt; 
            [visible] =&gt; 1
            [availablefrom] =&gt; 0
            [availableuntil] =&gt; 0
            [available] =&gt; 1
            [timecreated] =&gt; 1561645727
            [timemodified] =&gt; 1561645727
            [usermodified] =&gt; 2
            [icon] =&gt; 
            [exceptionssent] =&gt; 0
            [audiencevisible] =&gt; 2
            [certifid] =&gt; 
            [assignmentsdeferred] =&gt; 0
            [allowextensionrequests] =&gt; 1
        )

    [3] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 3
            [category] =&gt; 1
            [sortorder] =&gt; 2
            [fullname] =&gt; Certification program fullname 101
            [shortname] =&gt; CP101
            [idnumber] =&gt; S02
            [summary] =&gt; 
            [endnote] =&gt; 
            [visible] =&gt; 1
            [availablefrom] =&gt; 0
            [availableuntil] =&gt; 0
            [available] =&gt; 1
            [timecreated] =&gt; 1561707524
            [timemodified] =&gt; 1561707584
            [usermodified] =&gt; 2
            [icon] =&gt; 
            [exceptionssent] =&gt; 1
            [audiencevisible] =&gt; 2
            [certifid] =&gt; 2
            [assignmentsdeferred] =&gt; 0
            [allowextensionrequests] =&gt; 1
        )

)
```

Using this I get all the users that own this certificate with this(in a foreach):

```
$usrwcert = $DB->get_records('certif_completion', array('certifid' => $cert->certifid), '', $fields = '*');
```

and then I just do another foreach on this usrwcert and try and make a list of users with the results of it.

The thing is that each user has two certificates, therefore I get my users twice in the list and thats not something I want.

The print_r of usrwcert returns:

```
Array
(
    [2] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 2
            [certifid] =&gt; 1
            [userid] =&gt; 2
            [certifpath] =&gt; 3
            [status] =&gt; 4
            [renewalstatus] =&gt; 0
            [timewindowopens] =&gt; 1590665879
            [timeexpires] =&gt; 1593344279
            [timecompleted] =&gt; 1561637992
            [timemodified] =&gt; 1561661794
        )

    [1] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 1
            [certifid] =&gt; 1
            [userid] =&gt; 3
            [certifpath] =&gt; 2
            [status] =&gt; 3
            [renewalstatus] =&gt; 0
            [timewindowopens] =&gt; 1590666730
            [timeexpires] =&gt; 1593345130
            [timecompleted] =&gt; 1561665963
            [timemodified] =&gt; 1561709174
        )

)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [3] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 3
            [certifid] =&gt; 2
            [userid] =&gt; 2
            [certifpath] =&gt; 2
            [status] =&gt; 3
            [renewalstatus] =&gt; 0
            [timewindowopens] =&gt; 1590651581
            [timeexpires] =&gt; 1593329981
            [timecompleted] =&gt; 1561707581
            [timemodified] =&gt; 1561707582
        )

    [4] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 4
            [certifid] =&gt; 2
            [userid] =&gt; 3
            [certifpath] =&gt; 2
            [status] =&gt; 3
            [renewalstatus] =&gt; 0
            [timewindowopens] =&gt; 1590651583
            [timeexpires] =&gt; 1593329983
            [timecompleted] =&gt; 1561707583
            [timemodified] =&gt; 1561707584
        )

)
```

How can I return only the unique fields in the last foreach?
Here is my full code:

```
$certificates= $DB->get_records('prog', array('category'=>$_POST['something']),'', $fields='*');
foreach($certificates as $cert) {

            $usrwcert = $DB->get_records('certif_completion', array('certifid' => $cert->certifid), '', $fields = '*');

                foreach($usrwcert as $user){
                $userdet = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $user->userid), $fields = '*');
                 $mform->addElement('html', '<option value="'.$userdet->id.'">'.$userdet->firstname.' '.$userdet->lastname.' ('.$userdet->username.', '.$userdet->email.')</option>');

            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `DISTINCT certifid ` in your query

Comment: unfortunately I can't

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `break` to execute the last `foreach` only once, in this way you can avoid the next record for the same user

```
foreach($usrwcert as $user){
    $userdet = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $user->userid), $fields = '*');
    $mform->addElement('html', '<option value="'.$userdet->id.'">'.$userdet->firstname.' '.$userdet->lastname.' ('.$userdet->username.', '.$userdet->email.')</option>');
    break;
}
```

Comment: this indeed outputs only two values but the two values are from the same certificate id. therefore, the user is duplicated

Comment: Which variable having the 2 same records `$userdet ` OR `$usrwcert` ?

Comment: well $usrwcert contains 4 arrays , 1 array for each certificate but I only need 1 array for each user.

Comment: @john331 break should work, another solution is you can use the first index of the `$usrwcert ` instead of the `foreach` for example `$user = $usrwcert [0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
this works


$unica=array();
    foreach($usrwcert as $user){
                if(!in_array($user->userid,$unica)){
                $userdet = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $user->userid), $fields = '*');
                $mform->addElement('html', '<option value="' . $userdet->id . '">' . $userdet->firstname . ' ' . $userdet->lastname . ' (' . $userdet->username . ', ' . $userdet->email . ')</option>');
                }
                $unica[]=$user->userid;
            }
```